# Run AVA tests with .js extensions as ES Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, ava

I have a JavaScript project where the frontend uses ES Modules (built with babel / webpack) and the backend uses CommonJS modules.  All files use the `.js` extension.  Given this mix and the file extension convention, I can't set `"type": "module"` in my project's `package.json`.

I'm using AVA to run unit tests across the frontend and backend.  Is there a way to run the frontend tests as ES Modules and the backend tests as CommonJS modules?